# How to read from Dynamic variable, ValueKind=Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I get a dynamic variable, which lists itself as ValueKind=Array, and I can see some strings in there as

`["a", "b"]...`

I get it from:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic?> dictionary = 
  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(response);
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("memberList", out dynamic? value))
  // here this is the "value"
```

How do I read from that?

I ask here, as google will find anything on Arrays and Dynamic and Dynamic arrays, but not on this subject

Comment: We need more info. What is the context for the surrounding code? Where and how do you receive the data?

Comment: When you say `ValueKind` do you mean `JsonElement.ValueKind`?

Comment: Be careful with the word 'dynamic'. A variable that changes content in runtime is usually just called a *variable*. If you want to be specific, add *immutable* or *mutable* depending if it can change or not. A *dynamic array* is usually called a *List* (see `List<T>`). The *dynamic* keyword is used when the **type** of a variable changes at runtime.

Comment: This is first time I hit something like this, so I did not know how to search this. I will update the post for future readers

Answer (score 2):

If you know it will be an array, you can just treat it as an array, but intellisense cannot help you, because it doesn't know what type it will be.

For example, this would work, if the dynamic is an array:

`var myListVariable =  myDynamicVariable.ToList();`

*[edit:]*

But, as per a comment above, it looks like it is a json array, so you would use something like this:

```
var yourStringList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(yourDynamicObject);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#824-the-dynamic-type

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried similar, but as it was first I did something wrong